# Executing a try/catch within a while loop

Tags: exception, while-loop, try-catch, nested-loops, inputmismatchexception

I am trying to execute a try catch block within a while loop.  When I ask the user to enter a number (which should be a double) I use a try catch to catch any input mismatch exceptions. I nested this inside a while loop so that if any exceptions are caught, the user may re-enter their input as necessary. The problem is that if an exception is caught, the scanner will not allow the user to re-enter their input for some reason. The errors are caught during the second iteration when you return to the line that says hours = kb.nextDouble. Here is the code.

```
boolean condition = true;
while(condition==true) {
    try {
    // prompt user to enter hours of service used
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of hours of service you  have used: ");
    hours = kb.nextDouble();
    // validate hours
    while(hours <=0){
    System.out.println("You must enter a positive number.");
    hours = kb.nextDouble();    
    } condition = false;
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime){
        System.out.println("You must enter a decimal value for hours.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc for [Class Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> "When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
>   pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
>   or skipped via some other method."

Putting kb.next() in the catch block would serve to skip the offending input.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!